# What is this distribution???

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from a population with 
$E(X_i) = \mu$   for all $i \in \{1,\ldots, n \}$.

Define

$
  Y_i 
= \begin{cases}
  1 & \mbox{ if } X_i < \mu \\
  0 & \mbox{ if }  X_i > \mu \\
  \end{cases}
$

**1) Determine the distribution of $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ (name and parameters)**

Is there anyone who can give me a bit of guidance here. I think it's a
 binomial, but whatever $p = $ is unclear to me.

Comment: Let $P(Y_i = 1) = p$ and $P(Y_i = 0) = 1-p$. What's the probability that $Y_1+\ldots+Y_n = m$, i.e. that exactly $m$ out of $n$ times you got $Y_i=1$?

Comment: $Y_i$ is not entirely defined, since it is possible that $X_i=\mu$. So we need to fix the definition of $Y_i$ by saying say $Y_i=1$ if $X_i\le \mu$. No fix is needed if we are drawing from a continuous distribution. After the fix, $Y$ is binomial. We cannot say anything useful about $p$ in general.

Comment: Duplicate of the first part of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/725638/15941).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, this is binomial.

Hint: Each $Y_i$ is a [Bernoulli random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with two possible results (say $1=$ success if $X>μ$ and $0$-failure if $X <μ$. The sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli with the same success probability $$p=P(X>μ)$$ is [binomially distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Relationship_to_other_distributions) with parameters $n$ and $p$, in symbols $$Y \sim \mathrm{Bin} (n, p)$$ where $p=P(X>μ)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The $Y_i$ are iid and [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) distributed. The sum of $n$ such rv's is binomially distributed.