# Determine a distribution with no parameters?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm confused by this question and I was hoping for some guidance some one to point me in the right direction

Let $X_1.........X_n$ be a random sample from a population with mean $\mu$, that is $E(X_i)=\mu$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. Define

$$Y_i = 1 \ if \ X_i \lt \mu \ and \ Y_i =0 \ otherwise$$

a) Determine the distribution of $Y=\sum_{1 \le i \le n} Y_i$ (name and parameters)

b)Determine the mean and variance of $Y$

c)Compute $P(Y \le 30)$ for special case of $n=49$ and $X_i..........X_n$ $iid$ $Exp \sim (\lambda=3)$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the distribution of $Y$ is Binomial with parameters $(n,P(X_i < \mu))$, assuming the $X_i$ are independent.

Comment: yeah I was thinking that because this statement i=1 if Xi<μ and Yi=0 otherwise only mention 0 and 1

Comment: In fact this will only be true if the $X_i$ are i.i.d. It is possible to write down an expression in the more general case, but it's a bit messy.

Comment: Please check that I have not changed the meaning of the question by my edit, and put it back the way it was if need be.

Comment: i'm not 100% sure if the meaning was change but i changed the notation back to how it is presented in the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last problem, if $X_i$ has parameter $\lambda$, then the mean $\mu$ is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Thus
$$\Pr(X_i\lt \mu)=\int_0^{1/\lambda}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=1-e^{-1}.$$

Our random variable $Y$ therefore has binomial distribution, $n=49$, $p=1-e^{-1}$. The probability that $Y\le 30$ is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{30} \binom{49}{k}(1-e^{-1})^k (e^{-1})^{49-k}.$$
This sum can nowadays be easily computed by software, including Wolfram Alpha. We can also approximate it. The distribution of $Y$ is not too far from normal, mean $49(1-e^{-1})$, variance $49(1-e^{-1})(e^{-1})$.

**Remark:** In the general case, $Y$ is the sum of $n$ independent identically distributed Bernoulli random variables. So it has binomial distribution, with parameters $n$ and $p$, where $p=\Pr(X_i\le \mu)$. Without further information about the distribution of the $X_i$, we cannot determine $p$.

More informally, if $X_i\lt \mu$, call that a *success*. Then $Y$ is the number of successes in $n$ independent repetitions of an experiment, so it has binomial distribution.

Comment: Thxs Andre you are the probability master

Comment: for a) $E(Y)=n*P(X_i < \mu)$ $Var(Y=n*P(X_i < \mu)*(1-P(X_i < \mu))$  ??

Comment: Those are correct, apart from a missing parenthesis.